# SQL Server - Bulk load blocking queries on heaps

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server books online say in [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> "Optimized bulk load operations on heaps block queries that are running under the following isolation levels:
>
> SNAPSHOT
>
> READ UNCOMMITTED
>
> READ COMMITTED using row versioning".

What does optimized bulk load mean here exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Optimized bulk load means SQL Server is using a special bulk load code path (fast load) and minimal logging.

These concepts are described in:

- [SQL Server 2016, Minimal logging and Impact of the Batchsize in bulk load operations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/sql-server-2016-minimal-logging-and-impact-of-the-batchsize-in-bulk-load-operations/)
- [Prerequisites for Minimal Logging in Bulk Import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/prerequisites-for-minimal-logging-in-bulk-import?view=sql-server-2017)
- [The Data Loading Performance Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd425070(v=sql.100)#updating-a-large-part-of-the-data-in-a-partition-or-a-table)

From that last link:

> Although readers under RCSI are not affected by X locks, there are two bulk load situations that will block RCSI queries (as well as NOLOCK queries) in SQL Server 2008:
>
> - When populating a heap with TABLOCK using BULK INSERT, INSERT-SELECT, or other bulk load operations. This is because the heap load acquires a BULK OPERATION intent exclusive (IX) lock and the NOLOCK or RCSI readers acquire a BULK OPERATION shared (S) lock. To bulk load a heap and permit concurrent readers even using RCSI or NOLOCK, you must eliminate the TABLOCK hint and thus give up minimal logging.